# Docker container ID auto-complete?

Tags: command-line, server, 22.04, docker

On Manjaro's shell (ZSH, I believe), after typing `docker container list -a`, if I type `docker container rm`  and type the first letter of an ID and press tab, it auto-completes. The same thing does not work in Ubuntu's shell. Is that possible with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Completion depends on the shell. At https://github.com/docker/cli/tree/master/contrib/completion you may see which shells are supported by docker. `Bash` should work after installing `bash-completion`. Have a look at the individual shell documentation for e.g. zsh.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that we are talking about the default one that comes with Ubuntu Server. I tried to install bash-completion, but that was already installed. So, to get container ID completion, I must use something like ZSH, not the default BASH?